# How to reference a cell in other sheet which contains a referenced cell not locked to this sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've searched for hours and couldn't find an answer to the following problem:

I have two sheets, Blue and Red.

I want Blue!A1 to be "exactly" like Red!A1 but I find this problem:
Red!A1 contains "B1+B2", both are Red's cells.
However, when I write Blue!A1 like this: "=Red!A1", the return value is something like "=Red!B1 + Red!B2", and not the "=CurrentSheet!B1 + CurrentSheet!B2"

My problem is that I cannot reference the Blue sheet in the Red one because I want dozens of sheets referencing Red in the same way, so when I change A1 in Red I change all the other sheets' A1 accordingly with their respectives B1s and B2s, not Red's B1 and B2.

I want to have a cell in a sheet which can be referenced by any other cell in any other sheet exactly like it was in the first place.

For instance, if I have a cell which contains =B1+B2 in a sheet, I want to reference it in another sheet in a way that the new =B1+B2 references the current sheet's B1 and B2 cells instead of the former one's.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Alexandre Trajano

Comment: Yes, I want to have a cell in a sheet which can be referenced by any other cell in any other sheet exactly like it was in the first place.

Comment: For instance, if I have a cell which contains =B1+B2 I want to reference it in another sheet in a way that the new =B1+B2 references the current sheet's cells instead of the former one.

Comment: The problem is that I want to do so for say 50 sheets, so when I change one cell in the first which contains a formula all the other cells from all the sheets thst were preciously linked would read exactly the same as the first cell.

Comment: I tried to input the very first formula as a string, but I couldn't find a way to convert a string into a formula yet.

Comment: I don't have a PC right now but can you enlighten me a little bit on scripting this function so I can research how to write it properly? Thanks

Comment: [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview), and the [Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/). You essentially want to set the formula of `Blue!A1` to be the same formula as that of `Red!A1`. If you are having problems with your code, you should then update this question with your code and ask a specific question. If your code works great, write an answer to your question with your code and accept it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look it up and update my post with an answer or a really tricky doubt.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Copy & Paste.

In Google Sheets, copy & paste iterates the formula automatically. If you change sheet, it will change the referenced cells to point to the current sheet; if you change location within the same sheet, it will shift the cell references according to how many columns and rows you shifted.

In contrast, cut & paste will move the formula without iterating the cell references.

**Solution 2**

If you have a truly large number of sheets you want to create based on a template and don't want to c&p a thousand times, you can use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

In particular, you will need

- [Spreadsheet App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) to create and access new sheets; and
- Functions that manipulate cells [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

You can enter the formula via Apps Script as strings.

For example, say you want cell A1 to have formula B1+C1 in a tab named "Sheet1". You can do the following.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var tab = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sheet.setActiveSheet(tab);
var cell = tab.getRange(1, 1); // The arguments are the row and column indices of A1, respectively.
cell.setValue('=B1+C1');
```

There are many things you can do here with the basic template. You can generate sheets based on some naming convention. You can generate formula based on the cell position. You can create a script that fills in the formula upon the creation of a tab if its name observes a certain rule. etc etc. And naturally, you can duplicate the formulas from one sheet. You will need [`getFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula) as opposed to `getValue`.

---

Note: you can also call 
custom Apps Script function directly in your sheet and write your cells using the output of your custom function. But in your case, using the range functions in Apps Script should be more efficient.